# How can I print an unsigned char from array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, linux, gcc, char

Trying to print the character ▒ in C.

I initially wanted to include that character in a `char` array, along with other standard ASCII characters (such as letters, so values under 127).

I have found that this character's ASCII decimal value is 178, so I thought I needed to change the array type to `unsigned char` to include values from 0 to 255.

The following code tries to print that character in the console:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    printf("Raw unicode call: \u2592\n");

    unsigned char array[2][3] = {
        { 35, 0x26, 0x27 },
        { 0x28, 0x29, 0x2A }
    };

    array[1][2] = 178;

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
            printf("Array[%d][%d]: %c\n", i, j, array[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

The code prints successfully the character I want using the `\u2592` call, but that is not what I want. I have to loop through the array and display every character. When looping, the output clearly can display < 127 ASCII values, but when asked to display the character 178, nothing shows on screen. Here is the output:

```
Raw unicode call: ▒
Array[0][0]: #
Array[0][1]: &
Array[0][2]: '
Array[1][0]: (
Array[1][1]: )
Array[1][2]:
```

Please help! thanks

Comment: ASCII is only seven bits.

Comment: Console output like yours will depend *heavily* on your system's locale and code-page settings. In [some extended ASCII](https://www.ascii-code.com/) the 178 character is a superscript 2. On my system, your Unicode call gives garbage but the second print shows the character you want.

Comment: `I have found that this character's ASCII decimal value is 178` Where did you found this?

Comment: Curious - none of the [14](https://pasteboard.co/g7AjFUueFoO8.png) available extended ASCII character sets on my machine have that character.

Comment: @tink: It's cp437, the default code page for the `cmd.exe` on Windows since forever (because it gives you access to a bunch of characters useful for making frames and icons and the like).

Comment: @ShadowRanger - and what does that have to do with Linux? There was no mention of windows or cmd.exe anywhere.

Comment: @KamilCuk I found the ascii code for that character on this website: https://theasciicode.com.ar/

Comment: @tink Yeah I just ran the same command as yours and I have the same output: https://pasteboard.co/9gOVHzfTggto.png

Comment: `35, 0x26, 0x27` What are these numbers? What should they result in?

Comment: @tink: Yeah, I didn't say they knew what they were doing. I just meant that the OP was definitely reading from a site that incorrectly conflated ASCII with cp437. The site they linked does actually describe it as "Extended ASCII", but it's pretending there is only *one* extended ASCII set, and being extremely misleading in the process.

Comment: Given that the Unicode escape sequence `\u2592` produces the result you want, your terminal is probably set up to process Unicode.  When you pass `178` to it, you are passing a value binary `0b10110010`.  That is a continuation byte in UTF-8 (the two MSB are 1 and 0), but it is not preceded by a byte that indicates that there should be a continuation byte.  That's an encoding error, therefore.

Answer (score 0):

In UTF-8, which is what you have to deal with here, a printable character is not always a byte, or an unfortunately named `char` in C.

That particular character is *three* bytes in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8): `0xe2, 0x96, 0x92`. (It is not 178.) If you want to "loop" to print UTF-8 characters, which may be 1, 2, 3, or 4 bytes each, you will need to determine the number of bytes for each character and then print those bytes together.

This table:

[image: Unicode code point to UTF-8 translation table]

shows how to tell.

The top bits of the first byte tell you how many bytes there are in the character. The subsequent bytes all must have `10` in the top bits. If those rules are not followed, then it is not a valid UTF-8 sequence.

Comment: How do I print the three bytes together? All of the other characters I need to display are one-byte long

Comment: You can `putchar()` a byte at a time. Stop after three. I don't understand what you mean by "I have to loop through the array and display every character." Do you want to put each individually on its own line? Then follow each with a `\n`. If you just want to print all the characters in a string that contains UTF-8 characters of various lengths, then just print the string. That's what your `"Raw unicode call: \u2592\n"` is. All of the characters are one byte, except for one that is three bytes. Though `strlen()` on that will give 22, it will print 19 characters plus one new line.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the very much very confusing world of encodings. **If** you have a *terminal* (the program you are using to *view* the data printed by your program) using extended ASCII code page 437, *then* the byte number 178 when rendered *by this terminal* is rendered as ▒.

*Nowadays*, [unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) is almost universal used, and you should read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

In C programming language we have (incomplete, limited) [wide characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character) and [multi-byte characters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte) and [locale](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale). And bottom line, everything depends on what you will be using to *view* the output written by your program, it does not depend on your program. All wide characters, \u2592 and multi-byte characters encodings take more bytes to store than a single `unsigned char`.  And to confuse you more, wide characters are UTF-16 on Windows, and UTF-32 on Linux.

I think I would just write a program to print Unicode code point [2592](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2592) like the following:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    wchar_t array[2][3] = {
        L"#&'",
        L"()\u2592",
    };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array); ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < sizeof(*array)/sizeof(**array); ++j) {
            printf("Array[%zu][%zu]: %lc\n", i, j, array[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```